# Update user token after roles update?

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

If I update the role of an user, this user has to disconnect/reconnect so that his new roles are taken into account and after that, he can access the pages associated with his roles.

How can I make sure that when I update the role of a user, this user is directly updated in his session, and he can directly access the pages linked to his new roles?

In Symfony 2, it seems to me that we should use this in **security.yaml**

```yaml
security:
  always_authenticate_before_granting: true
```

But after testing, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: the problem is, that the security token stores the roles, which - on creation - are fetched from the user object. if you update the user, it doesn't update the token. this is helpful for impersonating other users (and it's hinted at in the impersonation docs). so that's what happens. but to fix it is a bit more difficult, I guess, maybe you get an idea ;o) symfony 2 is really old, now ^^

Comment: Yes it seems to work! Now, is this a good method? Security level, is it OK? However, does this not conflict with other treatments? For example if I delete a role from a user and this must lead to different processing, will they be done before the token is modified?
(PS: sorry for bad english, I use Google traduction)